# How to split x and y coordinates in C++

Tags: c++

For my Intro to CS course I'm supposed to read in something like

```
N = 4
(0.5,1) (0.6,1.5) (0.7,2) (0.8,2.5)
```

and print out

```
X := [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8]
Y := [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5]
```

My code so far looks like

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int size;
  char c;
  double point;

  cin >> c >> c >> size;

  int N = size*2;

  double *A = new double[N];
  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    cin >> c >> A[i];
  cin >> c;

  cout << A << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This just reads in the points for now... but I can't get figure out the double parenthesis situation. And the rest of the problem. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think you'll figure this out. Just try to make sure to input a complete parenthesized pair in each loop iteration. Tip: using `std::vector` instead of raw arrays and `new` will save you much trouble in later programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think all suggestions of using vector and pair c++ stl are absolutely right. However, considering that mid_code just begins his journey of programming, I think **using arrays is a good way to practise**. I think you could use two double arrays to store information about points.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    char c;

    cin >> c >> c >> n;
    // store x, y coordinates in two separated arrays.
    double *x = new double[n];
    double *y = new double[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // Read x, y coordiantes and ignore the parenthesis and comma.
        cin >> c >> x[i] >> c >> y[i] >> c;
    }

    cout << "X := [";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << x[i];
        // Here worth beginner's attention.
        if (i < n - 1) {
            cout << ", ";
        }
    }
    cout << "]" << endl;

    cout << "Y := [";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << y[i];
        if (i < n - 1) {
            cout << ", ";
        }
    }
    cout << "]" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! This works perfectly. Thanks for that comment as well (Here worth beginner's attention). That comma would have been pesky.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this by **vector** and **pair** in c++. You can learn [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) and [pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/pair/) from this.

It's ok now, exactly what you wanted:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    vector < pair <double, double> > v;

    int N = 4;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        double x,y;
        scanf("(%lf,%lf)", &x, &y);
        v.push_back(pair <double, double>(x,y));
        getchar();
    }

    cout<< "X := ["<< v[0].first;
    for (int i=1; i<N; i++)
        cout<<" ,"<<v[i].first;
    cout<< "]"<<endl;

    cout<< "Y := ["<< v[0].second;
    for (int i=1; i<N; i++)
        cout<<" ,"<<v[i].second;
    cout<< "]"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
(0.5,1) (0.6,1.5) (0.7,2) (0.8,2.5)
```

Output:

```
X := [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8]
Y := [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5]
```